# WSO2 (IdM) cannot add user in Active Directory as primary user store

Tags: active-directory, ldap, wso2-identity-server

Environment:

- **wso2 5.3.0** installed on
- **Windows 7 sp1**
- **jdk_1.8.0_151** with external **primary user store** on
- **AD (Windows server 2016 Active Directory)**

Action:

- wso2 starts normally
- wsoadmin user is available in AD
- wso2 binds via **ldaps** to AD
- logging into the wso2 management menue on win 7 client as administrator ok
- all existing AD users show up in the wso2 users list view (only those with an email address)

If I want to add a new user "wsotest" an error is thrown:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient} -  
Error while adding the user to the Active Directory for user : 
wsotest
[...]
Caused by: javax.naming.directory.NoSuchAttributeException: 
[LDAP: error code 16 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C091027, comment: 
Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839 ]; 
remaining name 'cn=wsotest'
```

user-mgt.xml:

```
<UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
        <AddAdmin>False</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                <UserName>wsoadmin</UserName><!-- already be available in user store, here: AD -->
                <Password>admin</Password><!-- keep default; real pw is already set in AD -->
            </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName>
            <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="initializeNewClaimManager">true</Property>
            <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        </Configuration>

        <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
            <Property name="defaultRealmName">wso.ad.org</Property>
            <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="kdcEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldaps://dc.wso.ad.org:636</Property> 
            <Property name="ConnectionName">CN=wsoadmin,OU=AllUsers,DC=wso,DC=ad,DC=org</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">*******</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
            <Property name="AnonymousBind">false</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">OU=AllUsers,DC=wso,DC=ad,DC=org</Property>
            <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">user</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">sAMAccountName</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=?))</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*))</Property>
            <!-- -->
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="WriteGroups">false</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">CN=Users,DC=wso,DC=ad,DC=org</Property>
            <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">group</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=group)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectcategory=group)</Property>
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
            <Property name="MemberOfAttribute">memberOf</Property>
            <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="Referral">follow</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <!-- -->
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">false</Property>
            <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>            
            <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
            <Property name="isADLDSRole">false</Property>
            <Property name="userAccountControl">512</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>     
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>                     
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">false</Property><!-- default true -->
            <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
            <Property name="ReadTimeout"/>
            <Property name="RetryAttempts"/>
        </UserStoreManager>

        <AuthorizationManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
            <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
            <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">false</Property>
        </AuthorizationManager>     

    </Realm>
</UserManager>
```

embedded-ldap.xml

```
<EmbeddedLDAP>
<Property name="enable">false</Property>
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

add this property to the UserStoreManager within user-mgt.xml

```
<Property name="UserDNPattern">cn={0},ou=AllUsers,dc=wso,dc=ad,dc=com</Property>
```

thus the CN will be properly constructed. Obviously you have to adapt the structure and content of this DN string according to your AD LDAP.

Took me quite a time to find this, for [WSO2's manual](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEPCOPY420/Default+LDAP+User+Store+Configuration) is a bit misleading re UserDNPattern:

> The patten for user's DN. It can be defined to improve the LDAP search. When there are many user entries in the LADP, defining a "UserDNPattern" provides more impact on performances as the LDAP does not have to travel through the entire tree to find users.

Sounds like an option, but seems to be neccessary.