# How to fix " Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839]; remaining name 'cn=username"

Tags: active-directory, ldap, wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

I have created a secondary Active Directory user store in WSO2 Identity server.
Following is the configuration of the user store:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager">
      <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldaps://knpdc01.knp.nepal:636</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionName">administrator@knp.nepal</Property>
      <Property encrypted="true" name="ConnectionPassword">eyJjIjoiUWZNOWx6QmJtVmxFaDhsbzJuU2ZhaHF3b2JVckF0ckErSGRIeFZoMm5sSHJtci9mK0d1dk5WeklkcG1GTE$
      <Property name="UserSearchBase">CN=Users,DC=knp,DC=nepal</Property>
      <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">user</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameAttribute">cn</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(cn=?))</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
      <Property name="UserDNPattern">cn={0},ou=Users,dc=knp,dc=nepal</Property>
      <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute"/>
      <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
      <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
      <Property name="GroupSearchBase">CN=Users,DC=knp,DC=nepal</Property>
      <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">group</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=group)(cn=?))</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectcategory=group)</Property>
      <Property name="RoleDNPattern"/>
      <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
      <Property name="MemberOfAttribute">memberOf</Property>
      <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">true</Property>
      <Property name="Referral">follow</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated.</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password pattern policy violated.</Property>
      <Property name="RoleNameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="RoleNameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
      <Property name="BulkImportSupported">true</Property>
      <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
      <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
      <Property name="isADLDSRole">false</Property>
      <Property name="userAccountControl">512</Property>
      <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
      <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
      <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="defaultRealmName">WSO2.ORG</Property>
      <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
      <Property name="ReadTimeout">5000</Property>
      <Property name="RetryAttempts">0</Property>
      <Property name="CountRetrieverClass"/>
      <Property name="java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary"/>
      <Property name="ClaimOperationsSupported">true</Property>
      <Property name="transformObjectGUIDToUUID">true</Property>
      <Property name="MembershipAttributeRange">1500</Property>
      <Property name="UserCacheExpiryMilliseconds"/>
      <Property name="UserDNCacheEnabled">true</Property>
      <Property name="StartTLSEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="DomainName">knp.nepal</Property>
      <Property name="Description"/>
</UserStoreManager>
```

I am able to list users from secondary on WSO2 Manangement Console User List.

Also using WSO2 SCIM API, I am able to fetch the users:

```
curl -v -k --header "Authorization: Bearer <Token>"  https://172.28.1.101:9443/scim2/Users
```

But when I try to create user using the SCIM API using commmand:

```
curl -v -k  --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer eyJ4NXQiOiJOVEF4Wm1NeE5ETXlaRGczTVRVMVpHTTBNekV6T0RKaFpXSTRORE5sWkRVMU9HRmtOakZpTVEiLCJraWQiOiJOVEF4Wm1NeE5ETXlaRGczTVRVMVpHTTBNekV6T0RKaFpXSTRORE5sWkRVMU9HRmtOakZpTVEiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6WyJnd1BzVHg4UGU2czFKTVR4bVZOSEpMdllCZkVhIiwiaHR0cHM6XC9cLzE3Mi4yOC4xLjEwMTo5NDQ0XC9vYXV0aDJcL3Rva2VuIl0sIm5iZiI6MTU2NzY3MzY1MiwiYXpwIjoiZ3dQc1R4OFBlNnMxSk1UeG1WTkhKTHZZQmZFYSIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6OTQ0M1wvb2F1dGgyXC90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTU2NzY3NzI1MiwiaWF0IjoxNTY3NjczNjUyLCJqdGkiOiI4MDliMTg5Yi02ODRiLTQ1NjgtYWNiZC02MzRkY2JlMzk2NzYifQ.j-FEQwwSRrcFS1xSY435JEFg6hNrW0_KJK54pAgKPfgPJRz4J2yHVoLNf6dqTmoHB9q9OwcIjuCphVnVXchdK_Ew2fJMyOXttpgILXax_EOTLUgfLLMZv32vp2L_MJmjVCpLRCAndTxDa1gCtaB8thIptdx3MXaf4nudzUtuyyyTXd2q1-aTLpf4Av4SDi7d5BoSwWvUiwnxPAbbvAUZ-re4n1IVj2bPqgojIVgIcNE5vYTU_nbF7gZMB9jwZhj0xR2ytg53686lpAPjrEBqxRWuC9AxTwUhi3bC51Syp8E9V3LWSPqvzaeAl8-orUCWFykX3VIpUD1_9FU6UX3Xuw","refresh_token":"bc5d3a23-d67e-3c6f-80c8-941feb976d46" --data '{"schemas":[],"userName":"john","password":"Wso2@123"}' https://172.28.1.101:9443/wso2/scim/Users
```

I got following error:

```
Internal server error while creating new resource: Error in adding the user: knp.nepal/john to the user store. Error while adding the user to the Active Directory for user : john
org.wso2.charon.core.exceptions.CharonException: Error in adding the user: knp.nepal/john to the user store. Error while adding the user to the Active Directory for user : john


Caused by: javax.naming.directory.NoSuchAttributeException: [LDAP: error code 16 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C091027, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839]; remaining name 'cn=johngmailcom'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3175)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3100)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2891)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_bind(LdapCtx.java:423)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_bind(ComponentDirContext.java:299)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.bind(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:217)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.doAddUser(ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.java:169)
    ... 75 more
```

I have changed my claim mapping for secondary user store as mentioned [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Active+Directory+User+Stores+for+Inbound+Provisioning#c8e98ce704a84726a0784fef292e7bcb)

[Claim Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOm2x.png)

Comment: This is probably not related but `UserSearchBase` cannot be a leaf entry, it should be `ou=Users,dc=knp,dc=nepal` I think.

Comment: @EricLavault It can actually be a leaf entry, but you you won't get any other results other than that one object. But `CN=Users` isn't a leaf entry anyway, it's a "Container" (similar to an OU, except group policies cannot be applied to containers)

Comment: @GabrielLuci what would be the point of setting a search base that cannot match anything but itself ? The issue is about `cn=username` and `UserDNPattern` is `cn={0},ou=Users,dc=knp,dc=nepal`.

Comment: It has its uses (for example, setting the search base to a specific group to figure out [if a specific user is a member](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/09/13/one-user-is-member-of-a-group.html#the-slightly-harder-but-still-easy-way)). But by default, AD comes with a container (not OU) called `Users` at the root of the domain, so `CN=Users` would be correct for that and would not be a leaf. But you're right that there is a discrepancy between `UserSearchBase` and `UserDNPattern` here. Both should match.

Answer (score 3):

When we create users using SCIM (or the SCIM is enabled for a userstore), the WSO2 Identity Server persists additional SCIM meta attributes in the userstore such as lastModified and created claims. You'll have to map those claims to valid attributes on the Active Directory in order to support SCIM for a given Active Directory userstore. Refer to the [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/configuring-user-stores-for-scim-2.0-based-inbound-provisioning/) for more details regarding the same.

As an example, we can use the following claim mappings for the relevant Active Directory userstore for the local claims of the above-mentioned SCIM attributes.

```
http://wso2.org/claims/location -> streetAddress
http://wso2.org/claims/resourceType -> unixHomeDirectory
http://wso2.org/claims/im -> userWorkstations
http://wso2.org/claims/created -> whenCreated
http://wso2.org/claims/userid -> objectGuid
http://wso2.org/claims/modified -> whenChanged
http://wso2.org/claims/username -> cn
```

Additionally, you need to add the following properties to the relevant userstore config in order to map the binary attribute correctly into a UUID and also to transform timestamp formats correctly.

```
<Property name="ImmutableAttributes">objectGuid,whenChanged,whenCreated</Property>
<Property name="TimestampAttributes">whenChanged,whenCreated</Property>
<Property name="transformObjectGUIDToUUID">true</Property>
<Property name="java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary">objectGuid</Property>
```

Comment: In my case the reason for this *v3839* was an attempt to set the _company_ attribute with empty value (`'company' : ''`). Adding a check to set the attribute only if there is a value fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know AD, but I don't know WSO2 Identity. `NoSuchAttributeException` suggests you are trying to set an attribute that does not exist. Which one that is, I'm not sure.

I see your input is this:

```
{"schemas":[],"userName":"john","password":"Wso2@123"}
```

I don't know if it translates `userName` and `password` into the actual attributes used in AD, but these are the required attributes in AD for an account to exist:

- `sAMAccountName`: this is what is considered the "username"
- `cn`: the "common name" of the account (becomes part of the `distinguishedName`)
- `objectClass`: should always be "user" for a user object

Maybe you have to specify each of those by name.

Also, this did look suspicious:

```
<Property name="UserNameAttribute">cn</Property>
```

The `cn` attribute does exist, but, as mentioned above, it is not what is used as the username. The `sAMAccountName` attribute is what is considered the username. I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47453469/1202807), which uses this instead:

```
<Property name="UserNameAttribute">sAMAccountName</Property>
<Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=?))</Property>
<Property name="UserNameListFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*))</Property>
```

The [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+an+Active+Directory+User+Store) even suggests using `sAMAccountName` (in step 4).

That may or may not fix your issue. In that other question, they fixed it by adding `UserDNPattern`, but I see you already have that.

Also, as Eric mentioned in the comments, you have a discrepancy between these two:

```
<Property name="UserSearchBase">CN=Users,DC=knp,DC=nepal</Property>
<Property name="UserDNPattern">cn={0},ou=Users,dc=knp,dc=nepal</Property>
```

Is it `CN=Users`, or `OU=Users`? Both should match.